# How to install GeoAlchemy2 on qgis 3.28.15 and use its libraries on qgis console?

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, qgis-python-console, geoalchemy-2, sqlalchemy

I have installed GeoAlchemy2 and SqlAlchemy by using the osgeo command, but I am still not able to import the related libraries on the qgis console.

```
from geoalchemy2 import *
```

[image]

Comment: You need to describe how you have exactly installed the Python modules and to show the whole error message.

Comment: 1. i have opened osgeo batch file from qgis folder
2. It will redirect me to the qgis installation folder where i have used the below pip command to install geoalchemy.

"pip install GeoAlchemy2"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install `GeoAlchemy2` is by installing QGIS using OSGeo4W Network Installer:

[image]

1. After downloading, launch the installer
2. Select `Advance install`
3. Keep clicking `Next` until you reach the following window

[image]

4. In the Search box highlighted in red, write `qgis` and select the `Long Term Release` version. Change `Skip` to `Install`. In my case, it is `Keep` because it has already been installed.

[image]

5. In the Search box again highlighted in red, write `geoalchemy`

[image]

6. Click the word `Skip` - in my case, it is `Keep` because it is installed already - and change it to `Install`
7. Click `Next` to install the `QGIS` and `Geoalchemy2`

Open QGIS, use Python and write

```
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
```

You will not receive an error message:

[image]